# Dynamic SQL SSRS and Dynamic Row Grouping

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a dynamic SQL query that have dynamic column names. ( The resultset is then pushed into a tablix very similar to this setup(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BB9wvvkDY7Y ).It works fine. However, I need to establish a grouping on the row in SSRS. Due to the dynamic nature, the fieldname is not available before run time and therefore I cannot set a group on the row. I have tried several workarounds, using parameters like :

```
=JOIN(Parameters!DynamicGroup.Value, ", ")
```

(it is a multivalued field), but I cannot seem to get this working. At best, I get 1 row returned.
I may not be clear on this, but what I need is to be able to use the grouping when exporting to excel to have each group create a new sheet in the workbook.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide mocked up examples of your current results and expected results.

Comment: The JOIN is actually changing your array into a string which makes it worse to use as a grouping. How about using a generic name for the grouping field in your query?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I figured out what why I am only getting back a single row. It is because of the way the dynamic query is pivoting the resultset and then grouping it to display all columns(marked with number) as a row. So all fields with the same number becomes a row. When I add another grouping it is taking this qrouping, hence there will only be one row because it is unique(pivoted).
This leads me to think that I cannot get this done this way. Is there a way that I can have dynamic column names (based on Dates)? There will always be the same number of columns returned, but the content will different. I googled this, but I have not found anything that really solves this issue.